# Error 409 - Al abrir Modal por primera vez

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap, http

Al momento de intentar abrir un modal por primera vez, me sale este error:

> HTTP409: CONFLICTO: la solicitud no se pudo completar debido a un conflicto con el estado actual del recurso.(XHR)GET -

Luego le doy inspeccionar, veo el error, le doy abrir en una nueva pestaña y me sale el modal, luego vuelvo a la pagina anterior y actualizo e intento nuevamente abrir el modal y funciona normalmente.

Este es el botón que abre el modal:

```
<button type="button" id="expense_create" title="Agregar gastos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat m-6 btn-xs m-5 btn-modal pull-right" data-container=".view_modal" 
      data-href="{{ action('ExpenseController@createPos')}}">
        <strong><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>
  </button>
```

Y este es el código del modal:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {!! Form::open(['url' => action('ExpenseController@store'), 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'add_expense_form' ]) !!}
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close no-print" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Agregar Egreso</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sale_by">Vendedor</label>
            <select name="sale_by" id="sale_by" class="form-control">
              @forelse ($cashiers as $cashier)
                <option value="{{$cashier->id}}">{{$cashier->first_name.' '.$cashier->last_name}}</option>
              @empty    
              @endforelse
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="{{$register_details->location_id}}">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('expense_category_id', __('expense.expense_category').':') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('expense_category_id', $expense_categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => __('messages.please_select')]); !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="transaction_date">Fecha:*</label>
                <input type="text" name="transaction_date" id="transaction_date" required class="form-control" value="{{ @format_datetime('now')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="final_total">Cantidad*</label>
                <input type="text" name="final_total" id="final_total" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="additional_notes">Nota*</label>
                <textarea name="additional_notes" id="additional_notes" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary no-print" id="save">
          <i class="fa fa-save"></i> @lang( 'messages.save' )
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default no-print" 
          data-dismiss="modal">@lang( 'messages.cancel' )
        </button>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Sí, me ha pasado, pero sin ver tu código va a ser difícil ayudarte a resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion encontrada, el problema es el nombre de mi ruta: `/cash-register/close-register`,
al parecer ***hostgator*** tiene conflictos con nombres como: `register` o `contacts`.

Cambiando los nombres de las rutas ya funciona de manera normal.